# Case-Sensitive Argument Bash

Tags: bash, arguments

I have a trouble in a case-sensitive argument (bash), so basically when I type

```
./testfile -play
```

or

```
./testfile -p
```

or

```
./testfile -palalalal
```

the script has to run a "play" (name of function) that echo "test test 123" inside the testfile.sh

At the same time, it will also show error message like ***"invalid!"*** if I type

```
./testfile -PLAYYY
```

I really appreciate anyone that can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I see nothing to "help", only asking for someone else to write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` operator:

```
case "$1" in
    -p*) play ;;
    -P*) echo "Invalid" ;;
    *) echo "Still invalid" ;;
esac
```